# How to customize plotly title in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, ggplotly

Code for pie chart in plotly is like this:

```
USPersonalExpenditure <- data.frame("Categorie"=rownames(USPersonalExpenditure), USPersonalExpenditure)
data <- USPersonalExpenditure[,c('Categorie', 'X1960')]

p <- plot_ly(data, labels = ~Categorie, values = ~X1960, type = 'pie') %>%
  layout(title = 'United States Personal Expenditures by Categories in 1960',
         xaxis = list(showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE, showticklabels = FALSE),
         yaxis = list(showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE, showticklabels = FALSE))

p
```

How to add styling to a part of the title like - "United States" in bold and rest of the title in blue?

Comment: You can use bold in the following way. `<b>United States</b> `. But if you want to keep the color for United States black and make others blue, that seems pretty tricky.

Comment: Yeah, <b>, <i>, and <a> work in the title argument but not <h1>, <p> etc. I put the color using inline css with <i>. Couldn't find a better way!